# Concise way to prove the subgroup of $A_{12}$: $<(a,b,c)(d,e), (a,b)>$ is isomorphic to $D_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

Concise way to prove the subgroup of $A_{12}$: $<(a,b,c)(d,e), (a,b)>$ is isomorphic to $D_{12}$. This construction is "inspired" by $D_{12}\cong C_6 \rtimes C_2$ via "inversion" but I'm not sure if there is a way to prove this sort of construction in a concise and unambiguous fashion, i.e. why exactly $<(a,b,c)(d,e), (a,b)> \cong D_{12}$.

Comment: @DanielLi I am a bit confused - you are generating your group using odd permutations and claiming it is a subgroup of an alternating group? The permutations you have satisfy the relations I have noted in my answer, which arise naturally from the construction you suggest. But you seem to be off with your embedding - the symmetric group would work.

Comment: @MarkBennet that's a valid point. I have overlooked that. what if we try this: $<(a,b,c)(d,e)(f,g), (a,b)>$?

Comment: $(a,b)$ is still odd - you need $(a,b)(d,e)$ instead and then you have this within $A_7$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One concise way would be to express both groups in terms of generators and relations eg $$a^6=b^2=1, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$$